# How to use webview instead of intent in videoplayer plugin for android phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In my phonegap android application I need to get the video played for particular size.I have used video player plugin  for android phonegap from github.
I have used webview instead of intent in the plugin to reduce the size of the player.

But my problem is :
        1.when i use http://..../.mp4 it shows webpage not available.
2.when i use sdcard displayed the mp4 file as text file.
somtimes It show could not open mediaplayer and failed to find provider info for com.android.calender  in logcat

tell me the solution.

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Have you given your app permissions to access the internet? (Android)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```